# Rationals : Proof contradicts problem.

Tags: solution-verification, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I was trying to prove the following:

> Prove that if x satisfies
> $$
> x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0 = 0
> \tag{1}
> $$ for a set $(a_{n-1},...,a_0)$  then, x is irrational unless it is an integer.

I am sorry if this is stupid, but, what I did was, firstly, from $(1)$
$$
x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0 = -a_{1} x
\tag{2}
$$
then
$$
x= \frac{-(x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0)}{a_1}
\tag{3}
$$
so if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $x = \frac{a}{b}$, where clearly, here we have a fraction representing $x$, so how can $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$? Am I just stupid?

Please feel free to change the title and tag if you want to, I don't know what to make of it. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that the fraction $\frac{-(x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0)}{a_1}$ could be simplified into an integer.

Comment: No more than what I wrote. You are asked to prove that $x$ is either an irrational or an integer.

Comment: Is $\dfrac \pi 2$ rational?

Comment: I think that your strategy leads to a much difficult problem when you write $(3)$... try to use the rational root theorem.

Comment: @Gio: you can write that into an answer:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in\Bbb Q$, you can write it as $\frac ab$, with $a\in\Bbb Z$, $b\in\Bbb N$ and $a$ and $b$ coprime. And now\begin{align}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0=0&\iff\left(\frac ab\right)^n+a_{n-1}\left(\frac ab\right)^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1\frac ab+a_0=0\\&\iff a^n+a_{n-1}a^{n-1}b+\cdots+a_1ab^{n-1}+a_0b^n=0\\&\iff a^n=b\bigl(-a_{n-1}a^{n-1}-\cdots-a_1ab^{n-2}-a_0b^{n-1}\bigr).\end{align}So, $b\mid a^n$. But $a$ and $b$ are coprime, and therefore $b=1$. So, $x=a\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, thank you.